# Slick 3.1.1 insert element into database without AutoInc

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to simple insert an element into a databse without having an autoinc flag on the table.

Here is the table definition, I have all of the appropriate mappers defined:

```
class BlockHeaderTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[BlockHeader](tag,"block_headers")  {

  def hash = column[DoubleSha256Digest]("hash", O.PrimaryKey)

  def version = column[UInt32]("version")

  def previousBlockHash = column[DoubleSha256Digest]("previous_block_hash")

  def merkleRootHash = column[DoubleSha256Digest]("merkle_root_hash")

  def time = column[UInt32]("time")

  def nBits = column[UInt32]("n_bits")

  def nonce = column[UInt32]("nonce")

  def * = (hash, version, previousBlockHash, merkleRootHash, time, nBits, nonce).<>[BlockHeader,
    (DoubleSha256Digest, UInt32, DoubleSha256Digest, DoubleSha256Digest, UInt32, UInt32, UInt32)](blockHeaderApply,blockHeaderUnapply)
}
```

I'm trying to create a simple insert function for this table. Here is my attempt:

```
  override val table = TableQuery[BlockHeaderTable]

  def create(blockHeader: BlockHeader): Future[BlockHeader] = {
    val insertAction = table += blockHeader
    database.run(insertAction)
  }
```

and I'm getting this error for the types:

```
chris@chris-870Z5E-880Z5E-680Z5E:~/dev/bitcoins-spv-node$ sbt compile 
[info] Loading project definition from /home/chris/dev/bitcoins-spv-node/project
[info] Set current project to bitcoins-spv-node (in build file:/home/chris/dev/bitcoins-spv-node/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/chris/dev/bitcoins-spv-node/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/chris/dev/bitcoins-spv-node/src/main/scala/org/bitcoins/spvnode/models/BlockHeaderDAO.scala:30: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : slick.profile.FixedSqlAction[Boolean,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.Write]
[error]  required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[org.bitcoins.core.protocol.blockchain.BlockHeader,slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing]
[error]     database.run(insertAction)
[error]                  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Sep 8, 2016 2:11:32 PM
```

Comment: Where are you defining your insertAction? It looks like it's not inheriting from `DBIOAction`?

Comment: `table` is just a `TableQuery` object, `blockHeader` is an instance of an object that `table` stores. The `+=` is defined inside of `SimpleInsertActionComposer`

Comment: I guess the major question is if an an insert statement can be used outside of `DBIO.seq`, every test case they have using it uses that function: https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/898cb1871c610cea72027b266494f5bd83f770c9/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/InsertTest.scala

Comment: Not sure about this, but inserting usually returns the number of inserted rows. Try to change `table += blockHeader` to `(table += blockHeader).andThen(DBIO.successful(blockHeader))` if you want to return the just inserted object.

Comment: @Roman this doesn't result in a `Future[BlockHeader]` -- there has to be a better way to do this

Comment: This should result in a `DBIO[BlockHeader]`. You have to pass it to `db.run` in order to get a `Future`.

Comment: @Roman this does work, thank you for that, but doesn't this essentially just wrap `blockHeader` in a `DBIO.successful` -- this doesn't guarantee the insertion suceeded right? I would need to add a `returning` clause some how to do that right?

Comment: It is guaranteed. `andThen` is executed only after the first action succeeded. And you would use `returning` only, if you want to return a DBMS generated column. For example an auto inc column.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @Roman. If you want to write up an answer I'd award  you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `+=` returns the number of affected rows, which is usually 1. However to satisfy the signature of your `create` function, you will need to return a `BlockHeader`. You can do this by simply chain a `DBIO.successful()` action that returns your "insert" value:

```
def create(blockHeader: BlockHeader): Future[BlockHeader] = {
  val insertion: DBIO[BlockHeader] = (table += blockHeader).andThen(DBIO.successful(blockHeader))
  database.run(insertAction)
}
```

`andThen` is executed just after the first action suceeded, and will return the value of the second action.

Do not confuse with `returning`. With `returning`you can change the value that `+=` and `++=` returns. Said this, most of DBMS only allow to return a single, auto incremented primary key. For example if `hash` was an auto incremented value, you can return it like this:

```
val hash = (table returning table.map(_.hash)) += blockHeader
```

And to go a little further, you can also insert that value in your `BlockHeader`object using `into`:

```
val blockHeaderWithHash = (table returning table.map(_.hash) into ((blockHeader, hash) => blockHeader.copy(hash = hash))) += blockHeader
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `insertAction` returns a number of rows that were inserted, so you should map on that value and check if the operation was successful:

```
def create(blockHeader: BlockHeader): Future[BlockHeader] = {
  val insertAction = (table += blockHeader).flatMap {
    case 0 => DBIO.failed(new Exception("Failed to insert `BlockHeader` object"))
    case _ => DBIO.successful(blockHeader)
  }

  db.run(insertAction)
}
```